# Right-align table-cell div position

Tags: html, css

I'm creating somekind of a toolbar with buttons using `display: table-cell`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#docs {
    color: #333
}

#docs .docs-header {
    height: 40px;
    background: #efefef;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#docs .docs-header-item {
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 13px 0 5px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#docs .docs-header-item:hover {
    background: #e0e0e0
}
```

```html
<div id="docs">
  <div class="docs-header">
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #1
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #2
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #3
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works well, but I would like to align some of those buttons to the right of the bar, like the *Item #4* in the image below:

[image]

I could not get it to work using `float: right` neither `position: absolute; right: 0` for `.docs-header-item`. Is this even possible without major changes?

Comment: look at the bootstrap css and see how they do `pull-right`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it just uses `float: right`. I tried that, but it messes the layout.

Comment: Yes you have to look at the entire CSS and how they manage to use `pull-right` class that within there.  One option would be just to include that CSS but that might be more than you want/need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily with a flexbox. The trick is to set to the element, that you want to start aligning right from, `margin-left: auto`, and it will push the rest right (see comments in the CSS):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#docs {
  color: #333
}
#docs .docs-header {
  /** change the display to flex **/
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
#docs .docs-header-item {
  /** you can't use vertical-align, so set line-height **/
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 13px 0 5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#docs .docs-header-item:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0
}

/** add this class to the element you want to start aligning right from **/
#docs .to-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="docs">
  <div class="docs-header">
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #1
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item to-right">
      Item #2
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #3
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just add `display: flex` on parent element, and `margin-left: auto` on item you want to move to right. Also to vertically center items you can add `align-items: center`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#docs {
  color: #333
}

#docs .docs-header {
  height: 40px;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#docs .docs-header-item {
  padding: 0 13px 0 5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#docs .docs-header-item:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

#docs .docs-header-item:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0
}
```

```html
<div id="docs">
  <div class="docs-header">
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #1
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #2
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #3
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
      Item #4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I will accept @OriDrori's because he answered first.

Comment: Sure, glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

Divide your `.docs-header` into two parts, `left` & `right` and `float: left` & `float: right` respectively. Like:

```
#docs .docs-header.left {
    float: left;
}

#docs .docs-header.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#docs {
    color: #333;
    background: #efefef;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#docs .docs-header {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#docs .docs-header.left {
    float: left;
}

#docs .docs-header.right {
    float: right;
}

#docs .docs-header-item {
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 13px 0 5px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#docs .docs-header-item:hover {
    background: #e0e0e0
}
```

```html
<div id="docs">
  <div class="docs-header left">
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #1
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #2
    </div>
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="docs-header right">
    <div class="docs-header-item">
    Item #4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but I'd rather not to change the html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use float right in .docs #docs-header

```
#docs .docs-header-item {
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 13px 0 5px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float: right;
}
```

And then reverse the order of the buttons in html.

https://jsfiddle.net/chris2001/b5Lt6wkn/1/

Comment: Thank you, but I will keep the flex solution as the other users proposed.

Comment: The issue with this is the `float:right` gets applied in turn as the html structure is processed by the CSS and thus the first element is then the furthest right, and thus your comment to "reverse the elements" and not the most elegant solution perhaps?